# How to properly synchronize a list being accessed by multiple threads?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, thread-safety, synchronized

I have a list that is being updated on one thread every 20 ms and being read on another thread every 16 ms. I have heard that in a case such as this it is generally better to use a synchronized list and not a `copyonwritearraylist`, correct?

Should I initialize this list originally as

```
List<Object> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

?

Or should I make it a regular list and then every time i want to read from it use a method such as

```
public List<Object> synList(ArrayList<Object> list) {
    return Collections.synchronizedList(list);
}
```

Sorry if this is trivial, I'm really not sure. Thank you so much

Comment: The first option.

Comment: The second one is useless. A synchronized list is only useful if all accesses to the underlying list are also synchronized on the same thing; basically, the only safe way to use it is to immediately wrap the list on creation, i.e. the first way.

Comment: @AndyTurner is there a way to do simple tests on these synchronized lists/maps?

Comment: @Faraz depends what you want to test.

Comment: @AndyTurner I will look it up. Thanks though

Comment: @AndyTurner I found simple tests that I was looking for: https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized-collections

Comment: What does "updated" mean? Does it mean changing a small fraction of the members in-place? or does it mean deleting/adding/re-ordering large parts of the list? If it's the latter, then you might be better off just having the producer periodically build and then atomically publish a completely new list.  Note, this is different from what `CopyOnWriteArrayList` does because with `CopyOnWriteArrayList` _each individual update_ triggers a whole new copy of the entire list.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a list that is being updated on one thread every 20 ms and being read on another thread every 16 ms. I have heard that in a case such as this it is generally better to use a synchronized list and not a copyonwritearraylist, correct?

Yes.

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` is only really useful when you have *way* more reads than write, so the cost of copying the list is offset by the faster reads.

You have roughly the same number of writes and reads, so this doesn't apply.

> Should I initialize this list originally as `List<Object> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Object>());` ? or should I make it a regular list and then every time i want to read from it use a method...

The second one is useless.

A synchronized list is only useful if all accesses to the underlying list are also synchronized on the same thing; basically, the only safe way to use it is to immediately wrap the list on creation, i.e. the first way.